# C# print report on A4 paper

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to use c# to print report on an A4 paper. I am beginner, I can use C# to get data from mysql to show on screen.

But  when I want to print it on Windows Application, How can I do it
in C# 2010?  Do I need to download Crystal Reports? My report is very simple

Answer (score 1):

You can always DIY, but the easiest and most scalable solution is to use Reporting Services or Crystal Reports or some other reporting library to do it.

The DIY solution would be to use printer directly. Like [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Printing-Using-C-sharp/).